# Find matrix $M$ such that $M+M^T=MM^T$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider all $d\times d$ real matrices $\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$. I am trying to understand the subset $S=\{M\in \mathbb{R}^{d\times d} | M+M^T= MM^T\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ .

I believe $S$ isn't empty, i.e.,  $S\neq Ø$. Let $M=M^T$ then the question simplifies to whether $2M=M^2$. By [eigendecomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Real_symmetric_matrices) $2M=U 2\Sigma U^T$ and $M^2=U\Sigma^2 U^T$. Any symmetric matrix with eigenvalues $2\cdot \lambda_i=\lambda_i^2$ works, i.e., $\lambda_i\in\{0, 2\}$.

I'm particularly interested to know whether $S$ has any non-symmetric matrices $M$, i.e., $M^T\neq M$.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $M+M^T=MM^T$ if and only if $AA^T=I$ for $A=I-M$.

Comment: I see. While this correctly reformulates the problem, it is not clear to me whether I can find matrices $M$ such that $AA^T=I$ for $A=I-M$ without making $A$ symmetric. Are there known constraints to be put on $M$ so $AA^T$ is orthogonal but not symmetric?

Comment: I managed to find one, but then $A$ becomes symmetric, which I do not want. In particular, let $M=2CC^T$ where $C^TC=I\neq CC^T$. It then holds that $A=I-2CC^T$ and we see that $AA^T=(I-2CC^T)(I-2CC^T)^T=(I-2CC^T(I-2CC^T)=1-2CC^T-2CC^T+4CC^TCC^T=I$.